# React state object property calculated from other properties

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-state-management

How could I do something like this:

```
  const [gameSpecs, setGameSpecs] = useState({
    cols: 10,
    rows: 10,
    numOfCells: cols * rows,
  });
```

I have read similar questions/answers for objects in vanilla JavaScript but they don't work with React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback initializer of the `useState` hook:

```
const [gameSpecs, setGameSpecs] = useState(() => {
   const cols = 10;
   const rows = 10;
   return {
     cols,
     rows,
     numOfCells: cols * rows
   }
});
```